# Unlocking used LWAPP (Cisco 1130AG)

Tags: cisco, wifi

I just purchased a used AP, and it turns out it's configured as an LWAPP. I know I can correct this easily, however I cannot get the unit to default its existing configuration. I've tried to power it up holding the button for ten seconds, and it still boots into the pre-existing configuration. What method can I use to get into this unit without a WLC?

Comment: FYI, I don't think that holding the power button down for X seconds will reset any [enterprise] Cisco AP to default values.  I've worked with a bunch of different types, manufactured as long ago as the early 2000's, and have yet to see one that can be reset to factory defaults simply by holding in the power button.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a console cable to it and connect to it using a terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

[From the quick start guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/1130/quick/guide/ap1130qs.html#wp30482):

> ### **Resetting to Default Configuration**
>
> If you forget your password that allows you to configure the access
>   point, you may need to completely reset the configuration. You can use
>   the MODE button on the access point to reset the configuration.
>
> Note These steps reset all configuration settings to factory defaults,
>   including passwords, WEP keys, the IP address, and the SSID.
>
> **Using the MODE Button**
>
> Follow these steps to delete the current configuration and return all
>   access point settings to the factory defaults by using the MODE
>   button:
>
> 1. Open the access point cover (refer to the "How to Open the Top Cover" section on page 2).
> 2. Disconnect power from the access point (the power jack for external power or the Ethernet cable for in-line power).
> 3. Press and hold the MODE button while you reconnect power to the access point.
> 4. Continue pressing the MODE button until the Ethernet LED turns amber. (approximately 2 to 3 seconds). Then release the button.
> 5. After the access point reboots, you must reconfigure it using the web browser interface, the Telnet interface, or the access point
>      console port.
>
>    **Using the Web Browser Interface**
>
> Follow these steps to delete the current configuration and return all
>   access point settings to factory defaults using the web browser
>   interface:
>
> 1. Open your Internet browser. You must use Microsoft Explorer (version 5.x or later) or Netscape Navigator (version 4.x or later).
> 2. Enter the access point IP address in the browser address line, and press Enter. An Enter Network Password screen appears.
> 3. Enter the username Cisco in the User Name field.
> 4. Enter the password Cisco in the Password field and press Enter. The Summary Status page appears.
> 5. Click System Software. The System Software screen appears.
> 6. Click System Configuration. The System Configuration screen appears.
> 7. Click the Reset to Defaults button. (Note: If the access point is configured with a static IP address, the IP address does not change.)
> 8. After the access point reboots, you must reconfigure it.